# Setting the SELECTED attribute on a JQuery HTML select list populated from a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I am running through a list of items in an array. Outputting those options to via *JQuery* to a html `SELECT`.

I want to compare the current item in the array to a previously selected variable and set the `<option>` attribute to `selected`.

But it fails to add the attribute.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**//PHP**

```
$myAnimalArray = some filled array();
$s_current_selected = "Zebra";
```

**//SOME HTML FORM**

`<select class="form-control" id="animals_select" name="animals_select"></select>`

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            let animal_array = <?php echo json_encode($myAnimalArray); ?>;
            let animals_select = document.getElementById("animals_select");
            let current_selected = "<?php echo $s_current_selected; ?>";


            update_animal_options(animal_array);


            function update_animal_options(optionsArray) {

                $(animals_select).empty(); //remove any prior entries

                for (let i = 0; i < optionsArray.length; i++) {
                    $(animals_select).append('<option value=' + optionsArray[i] + '>' + optionsArray[i] + '</option>');

// HERE IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS

                    if (optionsArray[i] == current_selected) {
                        $(animals_select).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }

                }
            }

        });
</script>
```

Comment: You can change `$(animals_select)` to be `$("#animals_select")` to be more jquery-like. Then get rid of that `let` syntax.

Comment: user `$(animals_select).prop('selected', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute `selected` is a part of `<option>`, not `<select>` itself. You should modify your code as:

```
function update_animal_options(optionsArray) {
    $(animals_select).empty();

    $(animals_select).append(
        '<option value=' + optionsArray[i] 
        + (optionsArray[i] == current_selected? ' selected' : '') + '>' 
        + optionsArray[i] + '</option>'
    );
}
```

ALso, it's **always** a good idea to wrap attribute values in quotes. Otherwise code like `value=Some value here` will not be treated as you expect.

Comment: I didn't think about using an inline if to just add the select! Thank you!